# How can I write sequential component with case

Tags: vhdl

Below code is not compiling. How can I modify it to make it works? Thank you.

```
case S is
when '0' =>
U1: hi port map (x,y,z);
when others =>
U2: hey port map (x,y,z);
end case;
```

Comment: Can you please add the error message?

Comment: illegal concurent statement

Answer (score 2):

Without the rest of the code there will be some guessing, but you have probably used `case` outside a `process`, thus the "illegal concurrent statement" message, since `case` is a statement that can only be used in a process.  However, component instantiation with `port map (x,y,z)` is a concurrent statement, thus can only be used outside a process.

VHDL is not a programming language, but a Hardware Description Language (the HDL part of VHDL), thus when writing VHDL code, think of it like describing a electrical circuit, and in this the parts are fixed, but the signal values can vary over time.

So, instantiate the components outside a process with `port map (x,y,z)` and control the signal values from processes, other components, ports, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As you are instantiating components, you are not within a process, hence you cannot use sequential programming constructs.

You can however use `if ... generate` which selectively generates hardware, on the value of `S` as long as `S` is a generic or constant. (If you could input a signal to `if ... generate`, that would require hardware to appear or disappear when the signal value changed ... not gonna happen!)

Note that `if ... generate` has no "elsif" or "else" options, so you have to express your example in a slightly more awkward fashion:

```
gen_S_0 : if S = '0' generate
   U1: hi port map (x,y,z);
end generate;

gen_S_others: if S /= '0' generate
   U2: hey port map (x,y,z);
end generate;
```